# I'd like to copy svn project to git with history

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I would like to copy svn project to git project on linux environment. Currently I'm having my project in svn repo with branches, tags and trunk folder structure. I need to copy everything to git repo including history. I thought of using svn2git but do not have a good idea on the steps that I need to follow.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-as-a-Client#_git_svn https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn

Comment: git-svn has limited support and depending on your repository it won't work. git-svn is only good if you want to push commits back and forth between svn and git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

svn2git is a great tool. I'm using it to migrate over a large project. You need to define rules for each branch/tags. Wild cards are your friend.

```
trunk/A/B
branches/Foo/A/B
branches/Bar/A/B
tags/Baz/A/B
tags/Foobar/A/B
```

Here are some sample rules. NOTE: Rules are run in order.

```
match /trunk/
  branch master
end match

match /branches/([^/]+)/
  branch \1
end match 

match /tags/([^/]+)/
  branch refs/tags/\1
  annotated true
end match
```

This will result in the following branches: master, Foo, and Bar and tags Baz and Foobar.

Something that took me a while to figure out is if you need to dig deeper into the path you need to use the recurse function. For example if a commit copies all of branches into tags, the path would just be /branches/. You need to rule to go down a directory.

```
match /branches/$
  action recurse
end match
```

Another great tool to use before writing your rules is svneverever. It will help you write your rules.

https://blog.hartwork.org/posts/before-svn2git-you-want-to-run-svneverever/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was hoping that I could migrate trunk, branches and tags without any another configuration change using svn2git. I have already created a authors.txt file according to the way that git requires it. Can you tell me where I should use these rules?
This is the guide that I'm trying to follow. https://gist.github.com/amura2406/a610a6a50690ceda96b6858f2435227f

Comment: It says that I just have to use the svn2git http://svn.example.com/path/to/repo --authors /path/to/authors.txt command.

Comment: I run it with the following options... `svn2git --identity-map=/PATH/TO/AUTHORS.txt --rules=MyRepo.rules --stats --add-metadata --fast-import-timeout=0 --debug-rules file:///PATH/TO/REPO` EDIT: I just realized you are using a different svn2git. https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git